# DLLNotFoundException The Specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, dllnotfoundexception

I make use of the Belgium Identity Card SDK for reading data from a idcard.
The SDK exists of 2 components: interface dll and a wrapper dll.

In VS2010, i can make a reference to the interface dll, but not to the wrapper dll, so I put it manually in the bin folder. When I migrate my application to another pc on the localhost, it is not able to find the wrapper dll.

Not even when I (on the 2nd pc):

-installed the sdk.

-put the wrapper dll into the bin folder and system32 folder

In visual studio, properties of the interface dll, I've set "Copy Local" to true.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

This could just be a difference in path names between machines.

I would create a folder at the top level of your solution and place these DLLs in there. Call it something obvious like "Solution dependencies". Then you can reference them as needed and set them copy to local as required. You wont always be able to reference a DLL, especially if it isn't .NET compatible.

I'm curious about your statement of interface and wrapper dlls. Is the wrapper dll not meant to be a .NET wrapper for a C++ style dll?

Comment: i don't know. I could not make a reference with the wrapper dll, so i supposed that is was not a .net dll. Creating a folder at top level didn't work for me. He still throw an error: could not find *the wrapper dll*